# "Subscribe to Reports" Permission in Spring '17 Release

Tags: reporting, permissions, licenses

Could you help me, please?

With the Spring '17 release, there is a new permission "Subscribe to Reports" (Subscribe to reports in Lightning Experience to schedule report refreshes and send notifications).

This has been automatically set as true in all permission sets with the permission "Run Reports" set as true.

This has, however, led to a problem:  I cannot assign this permission set to users with a platform license.  I get the following error:

---

Please fix the following:

Can't assign permission set ReportsDashboardsUser to user "XXXX". The user license doesn't allow the permission: Subscribe to Reports

---

What is strange also is that some of these users already have a permission set with "Subscribe to Reports" set as true and no error occured on the upgrade to Spring '17.

We have not enabled Lightning, we are only running "Classic".

So here are my questions:

1. Is the permission "Subscribe to Reports" automatically set with the Spring '17 upgrade when one already has the permission "Run Reports" set as true?
2. Should the functionality "Subscribe to Reports" work for platform license users?

Thank you for reading - if you can solve my issues, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

On profiles & Permission sets with a Salesforce platform license,you can set the "Subscribe to Reports" to false by following the steps on the user interface :

1. Remove the “Lightning experience user” + “Run Report” permissions + save => "Subscribe to Reports”is set to FALSE
2. Edit again and tick Run Report :  "Subscribe to Reports”is still FALSE.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you SophieD for the solution.  It is also possible to set the "Subscribe to Reports" permission directly to false.  Do you have any idea about the two questions I posted?

Answer (score 0):

The permission set includes a permission which not allowed for the user's license type. So you have to change the user's license type, or remove the permission from that permission set. And you need to review the user's license type to check which permissions are allowed.

Refer this link to know more about permission set license : [Permission Set Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_permissionset_licenses_about.htm&type=0)

Comment: Hello Tejas, thank you for your answer, but the question is very specific, not about permission sets in general.